# Why can't we see the electrical fields formed?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

Why can not we see electrical fields? What are electrical fields composed of that we can not see them? Or do I have a misconception about electrical fields?

Comment: Electric fields are _constructs_ which help us in visualing the forces on some set of charges. You **cannot** _see_ it. Along the same line of thought, can you _see_ force?

Comment: your eyes (retina) have bandpass filters in them that pass optical wavelengths around $400nm$ to $700nm$, frequencies $430THz$ to $750THz$  and thus you can only see those and not others. Static electric field has frequency $0Hz$ and your eyes are not sensitive to that, your hair can sense it though.